# Bar fixed on top, but only if the scroll tries to hide it

Tags: javascript, css

I have [a menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp9MD.png) on the highest zone of my web, but not on the top. I want that when the user scrolls the page it stays on the top, but only when it would disapear instead. If the title is visible i want the menu under it, on an apparent static position.

Is it possible without javascript, only with css? I see it on a website, but I don't remeber where.

Thank you in advance (and sorry for my ugly english!) ;)

Comment: This is only achievable through the use of JavaScript.

Comment: FYI, I found a live example of this effect. I recommend digging into it using firebug / developer console to see how they use javascript to create the effect. The website is: http://movethewebforward.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/QuVkV/2/

Here html structure:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='upper'>This is upper content</div>
    <div id='position-saver'>
        <div id='bar'>This is the menu bar</div>
    </div>
    <div id='lower'>This is some content lower than the menu bar</div>
</div>
```

This is the css :

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
}

#upper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#position-saver {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#bar {    
    position: static;
    height : 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And here is the javascript :

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    if ($('#bar')[0].offsetTop < $(document).scrollTop()){
        $("#bar").css({position: "fixed", top:0});            
    }
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < $("#position-saver")[0].offsetTop){
        $("#bar").css({position: "static", top: 0});           
    }            
});
```

Comment: I made a modification to your example. Can you tell me why it does not work this way? http://jsfiddle.net/vWv6M/2/

Comment: Changing the bar position to fixed makes its width relative to body, so you have to change the width too. Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/gabitzish/vWv6M/11/

Comment: $('#bar')[0] means you return the first #bar ?

Comment: I'm using that to transform the jQuery object into html element.

Comment: That's not vanilla Javascript. It's jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I've seen this type of thing on many site. One on 9gag.com

Anyway, you can use the `position` property of the css.

like this one: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cWzp9/)

```
#scroll-me{ 
    width:100%;
     height:100px; 
     background:#333;
     position: fixed;
     top:15px;
     }
```

The `position:fixed` with `top:15px` of the scroll-me div makes it always 15px on top

Comment: Using only fixed position will cause the menu to stay at top:15px all the time. @davidgnin want's the menu to scroll until the above title is hidden, and then stay fixed.